# Validate User Credentials from Azure AD in a Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, azure

I am a beginner with azure,I have migrated an on-premise application to web app in azure.I want to validate user credentials from azure AD.Currently the web application redirects to Microsoft login page for validating the credentials.

**What i want is to validate user credential from web application's login page using azure AD.**

Is it possible? If yes then what is the best way?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want is that the application should not get  redirected to Azure AD page for login & you want user to enter their Azure AD credentials on your web app itself and you want to somehow validate those credentials. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: you can use Azure AD graph API approach . check this post https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-lob-application-azure-ad/

Comment: Yes Gaurav this is exactly what i want.